# CloudFront Postman error - "request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I have enabled AWS API Gateway with Auth: AWS IAM. I successfully tested the API Gateway endpoint (Invoke URL) in Postman using the AWS Signature - Access Key, Secret Key, and Session Token.

However, when I replace the AWS API Gateway Endpoint URL with CloudFront URL and make a postman request I receive the below error. Appreciate any help to resolve this issue

**Error :** "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/Dev/nest/v1/api/customeronboarding/getquestionnairesectioncounts/DefaultCustomer\n\nhost:xreiuoaqw4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20230620T134921Z. The String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20230620T134921Z\n20230620/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request\n02f8382d6c68f1d7e8b3519475f0d9ae8c89e7f8b769103cd8b5f14cd24f189b'\n"